# jQuery change the select box value based on anchor clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When some one clicks a link I need the select box value to change

```
<a class="cli" href="0">Jan</a>
<a class="cli" href="1">Feb</a>
<a class="cli" href="2">Mar</a>
<a class="cli" href="3">Apr</a>
<a class="cli" href="4">May</a>
<a class="cli" href="5">Jun</a>
[...]
<a class="cli" href="11">Dec</a>

<select class="ui-datepicker-month">
<option value="0" style="display: none;">Jan</option>
<option value="1" style="display: none;">Feb</option>
[...]
<option value="9" style="display: none;">Oct</option>
<option selected="selected" value="10" style="display: none;">Nov</option>
<option value="11" style="display: none;">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Here is what I have so far, thought it was gonna be simple just cant wrap my head around it:

```
$("a.cli").click(function(event){ //when anchor is clicked
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".ui-datepicker-month").val($(this).text());
        });  
    });
```

I tried this too

```
$("a.cli").click(function(event){ //when anchor is clicked
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".ui-datepicker-month").val($(this).attr("href"));
    });  
});
```

Still didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `value` values are saved at the `href` attribute, use:

```
$("a.cli").click(function(event){ //when anchor is clicked
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".ui-datepicker-month").val($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: If you ever want to select by text content, loop through each child (`$(".ui-datepicker-month option").each(..)`, and check using `$(this).text() == linktext` whether the option has the desired value.

Comment: but the problem now is that the first click is not changing the value but the second click does...

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using? **EDIT**. Why are you using `display:none`?

Comment: Im using 1.6.1 but they are display none to replace the dropdown and use a links instead (visual appeal)

Comment: I have tested the code using jQuery 1.6.1, at: http://jsfiddle.net/tpR5e/. It works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Why change the value and not select the option that has the "clicked" value?

```
<a class="cli" href="0">Jan</a>
<a class="cli" href="1">Feb</a>
<a class="cli" href="2">Mar</a>


<select id="month" name="month" class="ui-datepicker-month">
<option value="0">Jan</option>
<option value="1">Feb</option>
<option value="2">Mar</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
jQuery('a.cli').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    jQuery('#month option').attr('selected', false);
    jQuery('#month option[value="' + jQuery(this).attr('href') + '"]').attr('selected', true);
});
```

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/jchiotaka/uaLXU/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
<a onClick="$('select.ui-datepicker-month').val('1');">Feb</a>
...


<select class="ui-datepicker-month">
...
<option value="1">Feb</option>
...
</select>
```