# Jquery show select box value based anchor clicked

Tags: jquery

To piggy back off this post 
[jQuery change the select box value based on anchor clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038000/jquery-change-the-select-box-value-based-on-anchor-clicked)

I can change the value of the actually select box

```
$("#id-for-select").val(2)
```

but not the result of selecting that value (what happens when the value is selected) as if it was clicked by hand

In my case I'm trying to change the dates on a calendar from http://teddevito.com/demos/calendar.php

I'm only able to change the value of the month select box from a anchor but not able to get the corresponding dates for that month since it wasn't actually clicked from the drop down.

Any way I can keep the dates corresponding with the month value in the select box?

Comment: You may need to re-apply the plugin to the input field after changing the values. I doubt the plugin is smart enough to check for updates on a timer or anything. Many plugins have an update() call that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a .trigger('change') on the end of your .val():

$("#id-for-select").val(2).trigger('change')

Comment: and you can also use .change(), which is shortcut for .trigger('change')

Comment: I spent an entire day trying to make a solution, I wasn't even aware of the .trigger() or .change(). Works perfect!!!