# Submit a form failed by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please see this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/7CCAW/). It should submit a form when selecting an option. It happens nothing when I selected the `first` option, and the rest of the options can goes okay. Could somebody help me ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to submit form when first option is selected?

Comment: @user1844933 submit button not needed to submit form.

Comment: I'm sorry. The link is error. The code link is right now. Thank you !!!

Comment: @changzhi what do you mean 'the link is error'?

Comment: the first option is selected, so you cannot select it manually, you need a placeholder on top of your options to be the default value

Comment: @DanielLisik he meant that the link was wrong and he updated it

Comment: your previous link was the way you should have done things.

Comment: It is onchange event so if an option is already selected you can not fire onchange without changing it/

Comment: Please follow this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038000/jquery-change-the-select-box-value-based-on-anchor-clicked

Answer (score 0):

As the first item is selected by default, it won't trigger change(). You can add another item as default like:

```
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
  <option value="4">4 Rate</option>
  <option value="5">5 Rate</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
 <div>
    <form class="speed_form" action="/dashboard/speed/" method="get">
    <select name="speed" class="{{id}}" id="selectRate" >
      <option value="0">-Select-</option>
      <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
      <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
      <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
      <option value="4">4 Rate</option>
      <option value="5">5 Rate</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="uuid" id="uuid" value="{{id}}">
    </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("selectRate").change(function(){
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).parent().submit();
    });
    </script>
```